# How to create a result to an empty state in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

This looks like a large script, but the functionality for the filter isn't that big. I'm having trouble creating a result for an empty state.

i.e.; If the filter selections don't match any object, then display **Sorry. There's nothing at this time**.

I have tried collecting all the chosen items and if total `chosenItems.length == 0`, then display a message... but I'm missing something somewhhere.

```js
//dropdown
let current_story = "",
  current_year = "";

for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select-wrapper:not(.clearFilter)")) {
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.querySelector(".custom__select").classList.toggle("open");
  });
}

for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__option")) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (!this.classList.contains("selected")) {
      this.parentNode
        .querySelector(".custom__option.selected")
        .classList.remove("selected");
      this.classList.add("selected");
      this.closest(".custom__select").querySelector(
        ".custom__select-trigger h6"
      ).textContent = this.textContent;
      if (this.getAttribute("data-year")) {
        current_year = this.dataset["year"];
        yearFilter(this.dataset["year"]);
      } else {
        current_story = this.dataset["type"];
        storyFilter(this.dataset["type"]);
      }
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  for (const select of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select")) {
    if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
      select.classList.remove("open");
    }
  }
});

// filter
function storyFilter(className) {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll(".article");

  for (const article of list) {
    article.classList.add("hidden");
    article.classList.remove("chosen");
    if (className == "all") {
      if (
        current_year !== "" &&
        current_year == "all"
      ) {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      } else if (
        current_year !== "" &&
        article.getAttribute("data-year") === current_year
      ) {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      } else if (current_year === "") {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      }
    } else if (article.getAttribute("data-type") === className) {
      if (
        current_year !== "" &&
        current_year == "all"
      ) {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      } else if (
        current_year !== "" &&
        article.getAttribute("data-year") === current_year
      ) {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      } else if (current_year === "") {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      }
    }
  }
  loadInitial();
  checkLoadMore()
}

function yearFilter(className) {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll(".article");

  for (const article of list) {
    article.classList.add("hidden");
    article.classList.remove("chosen");
    if (className == "all") {
      if (
        current_story !== "" &&
        current_story == "all"
      ) {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      } else if (
        current_story !== "" &&
        article.getAttribute("data-type") === current_story
      ) {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      } else if (current_story === "") {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      }
    } else if (article.getAttribute("data-year") == className) {
      if (
        current_story !== "" &&
        current_story == "all"
      ) {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      } else if (
        current_story !== "" &&
        article.getAttribute("data-type") === current_story
      ) {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      } else if (current_story === "") {
        article.classList.add("chosen");
      }
    }
  }
  loadInitial();
  checkLoadMore()
}


//global load more functionality
const loadmore = document.getElementById("loadMore");
const hiddenItems = [...document.querySelectorAll(".article.hidden")];
// const chosenItems = [...document.querySelectorAll(".article.hidden.chosen")];

// console.log(hiddenItems);

hiddenItems.splice(0, 9).forEach(
  elem => elem.classList.remove("hidden")
);

loadmore.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let chosenItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.article.hidden.chosen')];

  console.log(chosenItems.length);

  chosenItems.splice(0, 6).forEach(
    elem => elem.classList.remove("hidden")
  )

  if (chosenItems.length <= 6) {
    loadmore.classList.add("hidden");
  }
});

function loadInitial() {
  let chosen = [...document.querySelectorAll(".chosen")];

  chosen.splice(0, 9).forEach(
    elem => elem.classList.remove("hidden")
  );
}

function checkLoadMore() {
  let chosen = [...document.querySelectorAll(".chosen")];

  if (chosen.length <= 6) {
    loadmore.classList.add("hidden");
  } else if (loadmore.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    loadmore.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}

//reset button
let filterSelection = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown").forEach(dropdown => {
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", function () {
    selectedFilter.classList.remove("hidden");
  })
});

function clearSelection() {
  document.querySelector(".custom__select-wrapper .story-sel h6").textContent = "STORY TYPE";
  document.querySelector(".custom__select-wrapper .year-sel h6").textContent = "YEAR";
  document.querySelector(".custom__option.selected[data-type]").classList.remove("selected");
  document.querySelector(".custom__option.selected[data-year]").classList.remove("selected");
  document.querySelector(".custom__option[data-type='all']").classList.add("selected");
  document.querySelector(".custom__option[data-year='all']").classList.add("selected");

  selectedFilter.classList.add("hidden");

  let articles = [...document.querySelectorAll(".article")];

  current_story = "all";
  current_year = "all";

  articles.forEach(function (article) {
    article.classList.add("hidden");
    article.classList.add("chosen");
  });
  loadInitial();
  checkLoadMore();
}

if (document.querySelectorAll('.article.hidden.chosen').length < 1) {
  newsList.innerHTML = "<h1>Nothing</h1>";
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

button.clear {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

#selectedFilter {
  color: #005fec;
}

.nextcard {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .filter__settings {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .custom__select-wrapper h6 {
    padding: 0 3px;
    color: #a1b4c4;
    font-weight: 300;
  }

  .custom__select {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .custom__select-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }

  .custom__select-trigger {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .custom__select-wrapper h6,
.custom__select-trigger h6 {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .custom__select-trigger h6 {
    color: #005fec;
    font-weight: 900;
  }

  .custom__select-wrapper #selectedFilter {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #005fec;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .custom__options {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: #005fec;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .custom__options:before, .custom__options:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 11px;
    border: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #005fec;
  }

  .custom__select-trigger,
.custom__option {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #005fec;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .custom__select.open .custom__options {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .custom__option {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin: 1.5em 0;
  }
  .custom__option:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .custom__option.selected {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .custom__option.selected::before {
    content: "•";
    margin-left: -12px;
    padding-right: 8px;
  }

  /* arrow */
  .arrow {
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 2em;
  }
  .arrow::before, .arrow::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 0.1rem;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  .arrow::before {
    left: -2px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #394a6d;
  }
  .arrow::after {
    left: 2px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background-color: #394a6d;
  }

  .open .arrow::before {
    left: -2px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .open .arrow::after {
    left: 2px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .arrow::after {
    left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background-color: #394a6d;
  }

  .open .arrow::before {
    left: -2px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .open .arrow::after {
    left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter__settings {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .custom__select-trigger {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .filter__settings .custom__select-wrapper {
    margin: 0 2em;
  }

  .custom__select-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .custom__select-wrapper:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="listArticles">
  <section class="filter">
    <div class="filter__settings">
      <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
        <h6>filter by</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
        <div class="custom__select story-sel selector">
          <div class="custom__select-trigger">
            <h6>Story Type</h6>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom__options dropdown story-selector" id="storyFilter">
            <span class="custom__option selected" data-type="all">All</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-type="news">News and Media</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-type="analysis">Analysis</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-type="press">Press Releases</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
        <div class="custom__select year-sel selector">
          <div class="custom__select-trigger">
            <h6>Year</h6>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom__options dropdown year-selector" id="yearFilter">
            <span class="custom__option selected" data-year="all">All</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2021">2021</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2020">2020</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2019">2019</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2018">2018</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2017">2017</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2016">2016</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2015">2015</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2014">2014</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2013">2013</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2012">2012</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2011">2011</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2010">2010</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2009">2009</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2008">2008</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2007">2007</span>
            <span class="custom__option" data-year="2006">2006</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom__select-wrapper clearFilter">
        <h6 class="clear hidden" id="selectedFilter" onclick="clearSelection()">clear filters</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="row" id="newsList">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch article chosen news" data-year="2021" data-type="news">
      <div class="nextcard">
        <div class="nextcard__content">
          <div class="nextcard__date">
            February 4, 2021
          </div>
          <div class="nextcard__title">
            <h4>Red Fish</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="nextcard__footer">
            <a href="#" title="Customer Experience is the New Flagship Store" class="stretched-link nextcard__icon" rel="noopener nofollow" role="link" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch article chosen news" data-year="2021" data-type="news">
      <div class="nextcard">
        <div class="nextcard__content">
          <div class="nextcard__date">
            February 4, 2020
          </div>
          <div class="nextcard__title">
            <h4>Blue Fish</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="nextcard__footer">
            <a href="#" title="Customer Experience is the New Flagship Store" class="stretched-link nextcard__icon" rel="noopener nofollow" role="link" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch article chosen news" data-year="2021" data-type="press">
      <div class="nextcard">
        <div class="nextcard__content">
          <div class="nextcard__date">
            February 4, 2019
          </div>
          <div class="nextcard__title">
            <h4>Red Fish</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="nextcard__footer">
            <a href="#" title="Customer Experience is the New Flagship Store" class="stretched-link nextcard__icon" rel="noopener nofollow" role="link" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch article chosen news" data-year="2021" data-type="analysis">
      <div class="nextcard">
        <div class="nextcard__content">
          <div class="nextcard__date">
            February 4, 2018
          </div>
          <div class="nextcard__title">
            <h4>Blue Fish</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="nextcard__footer">
            <a href="#" title="Customer Experience is the New Flagship Store" class="stretched-link nextcard__icon" rel="noopener nofollow" role="link" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try and create a [mre].

Comment: That's toughe @ChrisG because all of this code is designed to work together and not independently. I need the CSS to show you the custom filter. I need the JS to operate the filter, sort the items and display a result.

Comment: Sure, but this a wall of code. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are creating a lot of unnecessary work for yourself here and it is pretty confusing to understand the filtering process given the amount of mutation you have in your script. You could try simplifying your script using non-mutating list methods.

```js
const list = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
const isAdult = x => x >= 18
const isEven = x => x % 2 === 0
const results = list.filter(isAdult).filter(isEven) // [18, 20]

// Evaluates to true if length > 0, false otherwise
if (results.length) {
  // Display results
} else {
  const el = document.getElementById('results')
  el.innerText = 'Results Not Found'
}
```